# Do I need to use both the C and C++ MySQL Connectors to connect with Visual C++?

Tags: mysql, visual-c++, mysql-connector

From what I can tell, most of the required files for C++ connection are not available in the MySQL Connector/C++, but the missing files are available in MySQL Connector/C.

Do I need both of the connectors to use MySQL in Visual C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know you can use the C connector in C++, right?

Comment: I was unaware of this. In that case, what is the point of the C++ one?

Comment: The C++ one is just a wrapper on the C one to make it object oriented